# Keras CNN model predicts the same value for all inputs and does not increase accuracy during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to follow the Nvidia self driving CNN paper (https://images.nvidia.com/content/tegra/automotive/images/2016/solutions/pdf/end-to-end-dl-using-px.pdf). However, when I run the code, my accuracy stays the same during training and the loss is extremely small. The model also predicts the same value for any input, very close to 0. The expected outputs are mainly between -4 and +4.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import scipy.misc
import random
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
import numpy as np

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(24, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2), input_shape=(66, 200, 3)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(36, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(48, (5, 5), strides=(2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(1164))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(100))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(50))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(10))
model.add(layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.add(layers.Activation('linear'))

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss= 'mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
epochs = 30
batchSize = 100
xs, ys = LoadTrainSet()
print("train batch loaded")
x, y = LoadTestSet()
print("test batch loaded")

xs = np.array(xs)
x = np.array(x)
#ys = tf.math.l2_normalize(np.array(ys))
#y = tf.math.l2_normalize(np.array(y))
#(Suggestion by Simon)Replaced by:
epsilon = 1e-12
ys =  np.array(ys) / tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.reduce_mean(np.array(ys)**2), epsilon)
y =  np.array(y) / tf.math.sqrt(tf.math.reduce_mean(np.array(y)**2), epsilon)

history = model.fit(xs, ys, batch_size=batchSize, epochs=epochs)
testLoss, testAcc = model.evaluate(x, y, verbose=2)
```

Training:

```
Epoch 4/30
5001/5001 [==============================] - 9s 2ms/sample - loss: 1.9974e-04 - accuracy: 0.0382
Epoch 5/30
5001/5001 [==============================] - 9s 2ms/sample - loss: 2.0004e-04 - accuracy: 0.0382
Epoch 6/30
5001/5001 [==============================] - 8s 2ms/sample - loss: 2.0040e-04 - accuracy: 0.0382
Epoch 7/30
5001/5001 [==============================] - 8s 2ms/sample - loss: 1.9986e-04 - accuracy: 0.0382
Epoch 8/30
5001/5001 [==============================] - 8s 2ms/sample - loss: 2.0064e-04 - accuracy: 0.0382
Epoch 9/30
5001/5001 [==============================] - 8s 2ms/sample - loss: 2.0014e-04 - accuracy: 0.0382
Epoch 10/30
5001/5001 [==============================] - 8s 2ms/sample - loss: 1.9993e-04 - accuracy: 0.0382
```

Predictions:

```
MODEL PREDICTIONS:
[[0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]
 [0.00018978]]
ACTUAL VALUES:
[[ 0.01337768]
 [-0.00774151]
 [-0.00143646]
 [ 0.        ]
 [ 0.00287291]
 [-0.00287291]
 [ 0.        ]
 [-0.00199569]
 [ 0.02122884]
 [ 0.01083373]]
```

First time posting, so sorry for any mistakes. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since your labels are rather small (<<1) it might be better to scale them. This is mostly because the squaring in your mean squared error makes small values even smaller (note that your loss is of order 10^-4) and more importantly has a derivative that is very small for small input values. This makes it hard for your model to train using gradient-based methods.

Alternatively you could try to use the mean absolute error since for that the gradients don't become small for small inputs.

Edit: after taking a second look at it I seem to have missed that you do in fact normalize the data with tf.math.l2_normalize. <s>But I think you need to pass it an axis argument (it appears that you are normalizing with the norm of the entire set of labels seen as a tensor).</s> Using that method you divide by square root of the sum of the squares of your original lables. Instead you should divide by the square root of the average of the squares.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210311/discussion-on-answer-by-simon-keras-cnn-model-predicts-the-same-value-for-all-in).